# How to determine if yyerror() was called while recovering from an error?

Tags: bison

How can I determine, from inside `yyerror()`, whether the error message was issued during error recovery?  [`YYRECOVERING()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Action-Features.html) can only be used in actions, but not within `yyerror()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Error-Reporting-Function.html):

> After yyerror returns to yyparse, the latter will attempt error recovery if you have written suitable error recovery grammar rules (see Error Recovery). If recovery is impossible, yyparse will immediately return 1.

When `yyerror` runs, the parser didn't attempted the recovery yet. It happens after the function returns.

Comment: Thanks, that makes it clear what my options are. I can delay printing the error until after `yyerror()` has returned.